# How do you compile a Glade/XML with GTK+ and GCC on Windows (MSYS)

Tags: c, windows, gtk, glade

Hey guys I've recently started dabbling in Glade with C. I have been able to compile a few GTK+ applications in C but I keep getting compilation errors when compiling the following C file with a glade file (taken from Micah Carrick's tutorial)

**main.c**

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void 
on_window_destroy (GtkObject *object, gpointer user_data)
{
    gtk_main_quit ();
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkBuilder      *builder; 
    GtkWidget       *window;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new ();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "tutorial.glade", NULL);
    window = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals (builder, NULL);

    g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (builder));

    gtk_widget_show (window);                
    gtk_main ();

    return (0);
}
```

**tutorial.glade**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE glade-interface SYSTEM "glade-2.0.dtd">
<!--Generated with glade3 3.4.0 on Tue Nov 20 14:05:37 2007 -->
<glade-interface>
  <widget class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="events">GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK | GDK_POINTER_MOTION_HINT_MASK | GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK | GDK_BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK</property>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
  </widget>
</glade-interface>
```

and compiling in MSYS with:

```
gcc -Wall -g -mwindows -O2 main.c -o program.exe `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

I get the following error:

```
main.c:4:20: error: unknown type name 'GtkObject'
 on_window_destroy (GtkObject *object, gpointer user_data)
                    ^
```

I've tried using changing tutorial.glade to an XML file but didn't change anything. Maybe I have to rename GtkObject to something different, or I missed a compilation flag? Sorry if it's a noob question, still learning :S

Answer (score 4):

Change `GtkObject` to `GtkWidget`. It looks like your tutorial uses the old GTK 2.0 API, while you are compiling using the current 3.0 API.

I suggest emailing whoever is hosting the tutorial to update it, or at least put a warning banner above it saying that it uses an out of date API.

Comment: It built :) however when running the resulting .exe nothing happens.

Comment: Maybe I need to add some libraries like libglade-2.0 to the pkg-config path for it to work  but I'm not sure how to do that, have been unsuccessful so far

Comment: I would suggest using a more up-to-date tutorial for the 3.0 API. Trying to teach yourself from outdated learning materials will just be frustrating.